# How to make Vimperator not to handle <C-Tab> and <C-S-Tab>

Tags: tabs, vimperator

I had my own behavior for `<C-Tab>` and `<C-S-Tab>` achieved by another plugin, but when vimperator is active, this behavior becomes changed to default one.

Is there a way to make vimperator not to affect tab switching? **OR**: Is there a way to make vimperator switch tabs in Most-Recent-Used order instead of standard order?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I found the solution:

1) Use [pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/) instead of vimperator. (pentadactyl is a fork of vimperator)
2) put in ~/_pentadactylrc the following:

```
nm <C-Tab> <Pass>
nm <C-S-Tab> <Pass>
```

Then pentadactyl will pass these events directly to Fireefox.